# Web Scraping with Python for Search Bar Input

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to build a Python code that will automatically input manual entry from a csv column into a search bar on a website so I don’t have to continuously go back and forth. Any suggestions on how I would start?

Comment: search for something on that website. Then look for your query string in the url string. Then make a request to that url, substituting the strings in your column

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.